# Using same json key for different data with C3.js

Tags: javascript, json, c3.js

I would like to plot two different timeseries data at the same time using C3.js, and they're stored in json variables with the same structure(shown below).

With the following code, the chart is overwritten by the second dataset, and cannot overlay two data. 
I think it is caused by usage of same key for different data. 
How can it be solved?

```
var chart = c3.generate({ 
    bindto: '#chart', 
    data: { 
        json: jsonVariable1, 
        keys: { 
            x: 'Time', 
            value: ['Value'] 
        }, 
        names: { 
            Value: 'Past Fatigue' 
        }, 
        types: { 
            Value: 'area' 
        } 
    }, 
    axis: { 
        x: { 
            type: 'timeseries', 
            tick: { 
                format: '%Y-%m-%d', 
                count: 5 
            } 
        } 
    }, 
    zoom: { 
        enabled: true 
    } 
}); 

setTimeout(function() { 
    chart.load({ 
        json: jsonVariable2, 
        keys: { 
            x: 'Time', 
            value: ['Value'] 
        }, 
        types: { 
            Value: 'area' 
        } 
    }); 
}, 2000); 



jsonVariable1 
"[{"Time":"2016-03-24T04:54:27.580Z","Value":0},{"Time":"2016-03-24T20:12:00.000Z","Value":15.292338671638888},{"Time":"2016-03-24T20:26:00.000Z","Value":14.592338671638888},{"Time":"2016-03-24T21:26:00.000Z","Value":15.592338671638888},{"Time":"2016-03-24T21:52:00.000Z","Value":15.159005338305555},{"Time":"2016-03-24T22:07:00.000Z","Value":14.409005338305555},{"Time":"2016-03-24T22:14:00.000Z","Value":14.292338671638888},{"Time":"2016-03-24T22:26:00.000Z","Value":13.692338671638888},{"Time":"2016-03-24T23:32:00.000Z","Value":14.792338671638888},{"Time":"2016-03-24T23:39:00.000Z","Value":14.67567200497222},{"Time":"2016-03-25T00:05:00.000Z","Value":13.37567200497222},{"Time":"2016-03-25T00:22:00.000Z","Value":13.092338671638887},{"Time":"2016-03-25T00:26:00.000Z","Value":12.892338671638887},{"Time":"2016-03-25T00:36:00.000Z","Value":12.392338671638887},{"Time":"2016-03-25T01:01:00.000Z","Value":11.975672004972221},{"Time":"2016-03-25T01:14:00.000Z","Value":11.32567200497222},{"Time":"2016-03-25T01:27:00.000Z","Value":11.109005338305554}]" 

jsonVariable2 
"[{"Time":"2016-03-25T19:37:00.000Z","Value":29.27567200497222},{"Time":"2016-03-25T19:43:00.000Z","Value":29.175672004972217},{"Time":"2016-03-25T20:02:00.000Z","Value":28.225672004972218},{"Time":"2016-03-25T20:07:00.000Z","Value":28.142338671638885},{"Time":"2016-03-25T20:13:00.000Z","Value":28.042338671638884},{"Time":"2016-03-25T20:25:00.000Z","Value":27.442338671638883},{"Time":"2016-03-25T20:27:00.000Z","Value":27.409005338305548},{"Time":"2016-03-25T23:02:00.000Z","Value":29.99233867163888},{"Time":"2016-03-25T23:09:00.000Z","Value":29.875672004972213},{"Time":"2016-03-25T23:27:00.000Z","Value":28.975672004972214},{"Time":"2016-03-25T23:35:00.000Z","Value":28.575672004972215},{"Time":"2016-03-26T00:07:00.000Z","Value":28.04233867163888},{"Time":"2016-03-26T00:27:00.000Z","Value":27.04233867163888},{"Time":"2016-03-26T02:45:00.000Z","Value":29.34233867163888},{"Time":"2016-03-26T02:49:00.000Z","Value":29.275672004972215},{"Time":"2016-03-26T04:54:27.580Z","Value":31.36666666666666}]"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the data set like shown below using `map`:

```
   var x1 = jsonVariable1.map(function(d) {
     return d.Time
   });
   x1.unshift("x1")
   var x2 = jsonVariable2.map(function(d) {
     return d.Time
   });

   x2.unshift("x2")
   var data1 = jsonVariable1.map(function(d) {
     return d.Value
   });
   data1.unshift("data1")

   var data2 = jsonVariable2.map(function(d) {
     return d.Value
   });
   data2.unshift("data2")
```

Then define c3 configuration as below with new dataset:

```
   var chart = c3.generate({
     bindto: '#chart',
     data: {
       columns: [
         x1,//jsonVariable 1 date
         x2,//jsonVariable 2 date
         data1,//jsonVariable 1 value
         data2////jsonVariable 2 value
       ],
       xFormat: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ',
       xs: {
         'data1': 'x1',
         'data2': 'x2',
       },
       names: {
         Value: 'Past Fatigue'
       },
       types: {
         data1: 'area',
         data2: 'area'
       }
     },
     axis: {
       x: {
         type: 'timeseries',
         tick: {
           format: '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ',
           count: 5
         }
       }
     },
     zoom: {
       enabled: true
     }
   });
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/0sokha6c/)